# Is it possible to avoid repeating MATCH(…) AGAINST(…) in MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

A typical MySQL FULLTEXT search looks like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST("value")
ORDER BY MATCH(name) AGAINST("value");
```

Is there a trick to avoid repeating this `MATCH(…) AGAINST(…)` in both the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in the `select` and refer to the alias in both the `having` and `order by` clauses:

```
SELECT t.*, MATCH(name) AGAINST("value") as relevance
FROM table t
HAVING relevance > 0
ORDER BY relevance desc;
```

The use of `having` without `group by` is a MySQL extension.

Edit:  As noted in the comments, the above query will do a full table scan of the table, rather than just using the full table index to choose the correct rows.  Of course, the full table scan will still use the the full text index, but it is missing part (and perhaps and important part) of the benefit of such an index.

Comment: Great, thanks. By "a MySQL extension", do you mean it's MySQL specific, and not part of the SQL standard?

Comment: This query will work, but it will be much slower than the original query because it can't use the FULLTEXT index. Instead it will do a full table scan.

Comment: Oh, that's bad then, they're not functionally equivalent? So really there is no solid alternative to repeating the `MATCH(…) AGAINST(…)`?

Comment: @IkeWalker . . . Yes, that is a downside.  I suppose MySQL keeps the evaluation order of the clauses, even with no intervening `group by`.

Comment: Thank you. It would be useful to add this precision in the body of your answer, so that anyone stumbling upon this Q/A does not blindly follow the advice without considering the caveats!